# What would be the proper way for dependency injection of App Executor class using Kodein in android coroutines Network Bound Resouce class?

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, kotlin-coroutines, kodein

I am looking for the right way to inject dependency of App Executors class using Kodein in Repository in Android MVVM pattern. I am following this guy

https://www.baruckis.com/android/kriptofolio-app-series-part-5/ 
For the rest of app I have used Kodein and for consistency want to follow the same pattern.

I have used this in My Application class but it is not working.

```
bind() from singleton { AppExecutors() }
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? Waht exactly is not working ?

Comment: This is not working. Below is the link to the AppExecutors file used in the mentioned open source project. And to use the object of it, I want to use dependency injection and code shared above is not working.

https://github.com/baruckis/Kriptofolio/blob/Part-5/app/src/main/java/com/baruckis/mycryptocoins/repository/AppExecutors.kt

Comment: What exactly is not working ? The code you're showing is correct. What is the expected behaviour ? What is the actual behaviour ?